# How can i add Map in record page

Tags: google-map, lightning-record-page

I'm new to salesforce and i'm discovering it.
I need to add map in my record page and i'm not sure how i can do that.
I read [this document](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.salesforce_maps_setup_nearby_maps_add_to_lightning_pages.htm&type=5) but i'm not able to install the packages. I also tried enabling the options in maps and location setting but still no result.

Any idea how i can do it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Setup -> Maps and Location Settings

Then enable at least the first setting (" Enable Maps and Location Services (powered by Google)")

This will automatically add a map to any Record Page field of type 'Address'. E.g. on your Account object, the map will appear as soon as you enter a valid Billing or Shipping Address.

[image]

Comment: Hey, I did this changes but still facing the same issue. Is there any other way?

Comment: Maybe you can add a description of the issue you are facing in your question? E.g. which record page (which object), where on the record page do you want it, based on which address fields,etc.